# Limit Azure search results by minimum search.score()

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am searching a list of products and I want to limit the results by score... for my purposes, anything with a score lower than "9" should be ignored.  This is easy enough to do when ordering by score as I can just cutoff returned documents when they drop below that threshold.

This is still difficult as if I am using paging, I cannot tell how many documents exist without paging through them until I hit my min score.

Also, some of our users like to sort alphabetically after they have their results.  This makes for additional logic issues.

Is there a way to exclude search results below a certain score in the initial query?  If not, is there a better way to do this without having to modify the data going into the index?

I am using Azure.Search.Documents v11.3.0 .NET SDK

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to exclude search results below a certain score in the
> initial query?

AFAIK, no. I tried to add an OData filter like `search.score() eq 1` however I got the following error message back:

```
Invalid expression: Unsupported function call: search.score. 
This function is not supported in filters. 
You may use this function in $orderby to sort results by score.
Parameter name: $filter
```

> If not, is there a better way to do this without having to modify the
> data going into the index?

Just thinking out loud, can you not implement the functionality where you intercept the response from Azure Search and not return any data where the score is lower than the threshold?

Comment: I've run into the same error... the latter option doesn't work too well when you are returning 1000's of records and need to support paging.  It's awful that there isn't a more clear way to do this, and since MS shut down their User Voice type feedback pages (which were pretty much useless anyway) there is no way to find out if this is supported / planned / etc.  Is there a way to affect the score so much that it doesn't return the search in the first place without changing the data?

Comment: @GauravMantri Can you please check the below question which is on a similar subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76900685/what-is-the-search-score-cutoff-under-which-no-results-appear-i-am-not-gettin